Extracting a fair coin flip from a biased die, with a time limit
There is a well-studied problem (including in several posts on this site) which asks for an algorithm for simulating a fair coin flip (or die roll) with a biased coin/die. Much work has been done on finding algorithms that are "maximally efficient," usually in the sense of minimizing the expected number of required flips with respect to a fixed biased coin. In this puzzle, I'm going to suggest a different measure of efficiency that doesn't depend on the underlying probability distribution of the randomness source.
The problem: You are provided with a biased 6-sided die, the only constraint being that no face has probability 1 of being rolled. You are tasked with simulating a fair coin flip with this die, within a "time limit." More specifically, let $n \ge 2$ be the number of times you roll the die before reaching a value distinct from the first roll. You will only be permitted to roll the die $2n$ times in total. For example, if your first 4 rolls are 1's and your 5th roll is 3, then $n=5,$ and you will be required to terminate your algorithm after the 10th roll.
Bonus 1: More generally, call a fair coin simulating algorithm $c$-efficient if for all sufficiently large $n,$ the algorithm is guaranteed to terminate in $\lfloor cn \rfloor$ rolls. For which $c$ is there a $c$-efficient algorithm?
Bonus 2: Is there an algorithm which is invariant under permutations of the 6 sides of the die which is $c$-efficient for some $c$ (possibly greater than 2)?

Here's how to do it in $2n - 2$ rolls:
Assign values to sequences of dice rolls, recursively in $n$, by reading off pairs of rolls and stopping if one of the following conditions is satisfied:

All $n - 1$ pairs of rolls match and the sequence of pairs is has a value, then assign that value to the sequence. (For example, if $AB$ already is assigned heads, then assign heads to $AABB$). Note that you have at most $2k-2$ pairs of rolls with $k-1$ pairs of repeats before the first different pair, so $2n - 2 = 2 (2k - 1) - 2 = 4k - 4$ and you haven't exceeded the bound.
Otherwise, if the $2k + 1$'th and the $2k+2$'th rolls do not match, return heads if the former is larger and return tails if the latter is larger.

It's possible to modify this algorithm to get down to $7n/4$. Consider the case of a two sided die for now, I believe the general case is basically the same.
Note that assigning $01$, $001$, and $1110$ to heads and assigning $10$, $110$, and $0001$ to tails splits the $n \leq 3$ cases into two equal probability buckets.
Then start reading off blocks of four repeats.

If you see a non-repeat in your current block, assign heads or tails as above.
If you can already assign a value to the sequence of values read off from the blocks of repeats, do so.
As a special case, if your sequence starts with $0000\ 111$, assign it heads and if you see $1111\ 000$, assign it tails. (Note that otherwise, you would have $0000\ 1111$ and $0000\ 1110$ both assigned to heads anyways.)


I'm not convinced your first algorithm is valid. For example, consider the sequence of rolls A=11112211, in which we have $n=5$ and an output of heads. It seems you're trying to draw a symmetry between that sequence and B=11111122. However, for B we have $n=7,$ and B can be extended to a length 12 sequence which outputs heads: B'=111111222111.

You're right, it needs to be greedy. I've edited the answer to fix it.
